# How to get value on original object with EnvironmentObject in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

```
class GameSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var score = 0
    @Published var score1:Int? = 0
}


struct ScoreView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var settings: GameSettings
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: ContentView3()) {
                Text("Score: \(settings.score)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView3: View {
    @StateObject var settings = GameSettings()
    @EnvironmentObject var settings111: GameSettings

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // A button that writes to the environment settings
                Text("Current Score--->\(settings.score))")
                Text(settings111.score1 == nil ? "nil" : "\(settings111.score1!)")
                Button("Increase Score") {
                    settings.score += 1
                }

                NavigationLink(destination: ScoreView()) {
                    Text("Show Detail View")
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 200)
        }
        .environmentObject(settings)
    }
}
```

So here When user has performed some changes in `ContentView3` & from navigation route if user lands to same screen i.e. `ContentView3` so how can I get `GameSettings` object latest value on it ? I tried creating `@EnvironmentObject var settings111: GameSettings` but crashes.

Comment: Your button increments the local object `settings` not the environment object `settings111`.  What is the crash message?

Comment: @Paulw11 `GameSettings may be missing as an ancestor of this view`

Comment: Then as @TaeeunKim says, you haven't injected an instance of `GameSettings` into the environment at some ancestor view.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add `.environmentObject()` to your YourApp.swift as well?
If not, you have to add it like this

**Life Cycle: SwiftUI**

```
@main
struct YourApp: App {
    var settings: GameSettings = GameSettings()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(settings)
        }
    }
}
```

**Life Cycle: UIKit**

In SceneDelegate.swift

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let contentView = ContentView()
        var settings: GameSettings = GameSettings() // added line

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(settings))) // added ".environmentObject(settings)" after contentView
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

**Preview**

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(GameSettings())
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Amit I forgot to write `()` after `GameSettings` and now updated my reply again. Can you try again?

Comment: I have used `@StateObject var settings = GameSettings()` & its working

Comment: @Amit Try with `var settings: GameSettings = GameSettings()` It should works also with `@EnvironmentObject`. For preview you need to add this line `.environmentObject(GameSettings())`

Comment: @Amit If my code works fine now, I would really appreciate it if you could check my answer :D